Nginx listens http but not https
here is my nginx config file,
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.xxxx.io;
    client_max_body_size 50M;

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/public.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend:4242;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
        real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
    }

    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend:4242;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

I can reach the api.xxxx.io with http://api.xxxx.io and see the logs. But when I try
https://api.xxxx.io I can not reach my website and there is no logs. I am also redirecting via cloud flare. Can anyone help

You probably need to create separate servers for 80 and 443 ports. The instruction

In opposite to what already said by the others, I can say that listening for both plain HTTP on port 80 and HTTPS on port 443 using a single server block is ok, and splitting your server block in two most likely wouldn't solve the problem. This is looks like a firewall or CloudFlare setup issue. What is your CloudFlare SSL mode (Off/Flexible/Full/Full (strict))?

I recommend trying a configuration like this. It’s important to properly separate ports 80 and 443 to ensure everything works correctly.
server {
    if ($host = api.xxxx.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 

        listen 80;
        server_name api.xxxx.io;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;

  server_name api.xxxx.io;
  client_max_body_size 50M;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/public.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private.key;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://backend:4242;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
      real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
  }

  location /socket.io/ {
      proxy_pass http://backend:4242;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}

